# PHP gettext (WordPress Plugin) change the font style

Tags: php, html, wordpress, gettext

Good Day Everyone,

I am currently developing a WordPress plugin that will be "translatable".

My problem that I have is if I use special font style in my string that is returned I also see the "html" police modification.

For example:

```
__('This <strong>text</strong> has to be bold', 'my-plugin')
```

How do I make it that "text" become "Bold" but that I don't see the  in the Translation table?

Comment: I don't think "police" is the word you're looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking a lot deeper in many documentations I finally came up with the solution.

In fact, the best practice is not to input any font style or html codes inside a translatable string.

The proper way is one of the following:

If you want to change the font style for only 1 word, and that word stays the same for every language, you basically have to remove it from the string and replace it with a gettext placeholder (as follow).

```
$string = sprintf( __('This %s has to be bold', 'my-plugin'), '<strong>text</strong>');
```

If your whole text has to be in a certain font style you have to add the code before outside the string:

```
$string = '<h3>' . __('This is a Title', 'my-plugin') . '</h3>'
```

Of course those should be inside a PHP tag.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to switch the text and the text domain:

```
__( 'This <strong>text</strong> has to be bold', 'my-plugin' );
```

I think that the result of your translation is used in some escape function. Can you try to bypass or to echo that directly using `_e()` instead of `__()`?

Comment: Not at all what am looking for... But my coding mistake was fixed in my original question... Sorry for that)

Comment: Thanks for helping me find my information I needed, I posted the solution below... But your help was well appreciated. and of Course I up voted your answer ;-)